# How to set the Jmeter environment for 100 concurrent users hits the server for 30 min?

Tags: jmeter

I want to set the jmeter environment for 100 concurrent users hitting the server for 30 min. just like for first 5 min users gets increased up-to 100, after that next 25 mins 100 concurrent users hits the server.

The graph for Users VS Time should looks like, Users Increases up-to First 5 min After that steady as 100 users for next 25 mins. Please suggest & guide if my assumption is Wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use any of these thread groups and update as given below.

**Simple Thread Group:**
[image]

**Ultimate Thread Group:**
[image]